# FullCalendar - remove time axis in agenda view?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I want to use multiple calendars and lose the time axis in the agenda view. So far i can get rid of the numbers/content in the column with the axisFormat option but i cant seem to set the width to 0 or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=971), there is no supported configuration option for this, but you can hide it through CSS.

```
.fc-agenda-axis {
  display: none;
}
```

That will hide the time axis.

Comment: This hides more than just the time axis. I will have to play around with class tags and see if i can get it to just the time and not the top header

Comment: I may be wrong though. It might be messing up the calendar's rendering. either way, its not having the desired outcome, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that i can get it to its smallest if i use the axisFormat and set it to a space (ie, ' ') and then set the width: 1px. If i go to fully 0px or display:none it screws up the calendar's rendering for some reason. If anyone know why, please let me know.

Comment: clean way to do this in FullCalendar 5.6: set `SlotLabelContent` to an empty HTML

Answer (score 0):

In FullCalendar v5

```
.fc-timegrid-axis,
.fc-timegrid-slot {
    display: none;
}
```